# Copying NSTextView Text

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nspasteboard

When I implement the following code to copy text in an `NSTextView` object by way of an action and then manually paste it into something like a text editor or an email client, the pasted text is one long string.

How do I retain the formatting of the text?

Thanks.

```
NSString *string = [outputText string];

NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSStringPboardType, nil] owner:nil];
[pasteBoard setString:string forType:NSStringPboardType]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to implement copying of `NSTextView` text. `NSTextView` is a subclass of `NSText` and inherits the `copy:` method.

To copy the current text selection to the clipboard, just call `[yourTextView copy:self];`.

As explained in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-copy_), if your text view is set to allow rich text, then the clipboard will contain a plain string (`NSStringPboardType`) and an attributed string (`NSRTFPboardType`).